# How to delete a specific part of an html file in Python

Tags: python, html

I am working on a html file which has item 1, item 2, and item 3. I want to delete all the text that comes after item 2. I can find item 2 in the file like this:

```
Item2= re.compile (r'(Item&nbsp;2)',re.I|re.S)
Item2match= Item2.findall(file)
```

but I don't know how can I delete the text that comes after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use string methods to split the html text and take the first part; [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) works much simpler:

```
file.partition('Item&nbsp;2')[0]
```

If you wanted to keep the `Item&nbsp;2` text too, use:

```
''.join(file.partition('Item&nbsp;2')[:2])
```

There is no need to use a regular expression here; you are matching literal text. Regular expressions is a wonderfully expressive and powerfool tool, but don't use it if there are simpler alternatives.

Demo:

```
>>> 'Some text with Item&nbsp;2 in it'.partition('Item&nbsp;2')[0]
'Some text with '
>>> ''.join('Some text with Item&nbsp;2 in it'.partition('Item&nbsp;2')[:2])
'Some text with Item&nbsp;2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?s)(?<=Item&nbsp;2)(.*)', '', file)
```

Example:

```
>>> s
'Item&nbsp;2...feiugeogherger\nfjweifjwef\nsfjioweiefjwe'
>>> re.sub(r'(?s)(?<=Item&nbsp;2)(.*)', '', s)
'Item&nbsp;2'
```